# Replacing invalid characters in the filename with dashes using AppleScript

Tags: javascript, regex, applescript, automator

My goal is to create service in Automator using AppleScript or Javascript which replaces all invalid characters of selected filename `()[\\/:"*?<>|]+_` and spaces with dashes (`-`) and make filename lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement of impermissible characters in a file/folder name can be achieved by utilizing a Bash Shell script in your Automator Service.

The following steps describe how to achieve this:

#### Configuring Automator

1. Launch Automator
2. Type <kbd>⌘N</kbd>, or choose `File` > `New` from the Menu bar.
3. Select `Service` and click `Choose`
4. At the top of the canvas area configure its settings as follows:

   [image]
5. Select `Library` at the top of the panel/column on the left:

   - In the search field type: <kbd>Get Select Finder items</kbd> and drag the `Get Select Finder items` action into the canvas area.
   - In the search field type: <kbd>Run Shell</kbd> and drag the `Run Shell Script` action into the canvas area.
6. Configure the top part of the `Run Shell Script` action as follows:

   [image]
7. Add the following Bash script to the main area of the `Run shell Script` action:

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   # The following characters are considered impermissible in a basename:
   #
   #  - Left Square Bracket:   [
   #  - Right Square Bracket:  ]
   #  - Left Parenthesis:      (
   #  - Reverse Solidus:       \
   #  - Colon:                 :
   #  - Quotation Mark         "
   #  - Single Quotation Mark  '
   #  - Asterisk               *
   #  - Question Mark          ?
   #  - Less-than Sign         <
   #  - Greater-than Sign      >
   #  - Vertical Line          |
   #  - Plus Sign              +
   #  - Space Character
   #  - UnderScore             _
   #
   #  1. Sed is utilized for character replacement therefore characters listed
   #     in the bracket expression [...] must be escaped as necessary.
   #  2. Any forward slashes `/` in the basename are substituted by default with
   #     a Colon `:` at the shell level - so it's unnecessary to search for them.
   #
   declare -r IMPERMISSIBLE_CHARS="[][()\\:\"'*?<>|+_ ]"
   declare -r REPLACEMENT_STRING="-"

   # Obtain the POSIX path of each selected item in the `Finder`. Input must
   # passed to this script via a preceding `Get Selected Finder Items` action
   # in an Automator Services workflow.
   declare selected_items=("$@")

   declare -a sorted_paths
   declare -a numbered_paths

   # Prefix the POSIX path depth level to itself to aid sorting.
   for ((i = 0; i < "${#selected_items[@]}"; i++)); do
     numbered_paths+=("$(echo "${selected_items[$i]}" | \
         awk -F "/" '{ print NF-1, $0 }')")
   done

   # Sort each POSIX path in an array by descending order of its depth.
   # This ensures deeper paths are renamed before shallower paths.
   IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a sorted_paths <<<  \
       "$(printf "%s\\n" "${numbered_paths[@]}" | sort -rn )"


   # Logic to perform replacement of impermissible characters in a path basename.
   # @param: {Array} - POSIX paths sorted by depth in descending order.
   renameBaseName() {
     local paths=("$@") new_basename new_path

     for path in "${paths[@]}"; do

       # Remove numerical prefix from each $path.
       path="$(sed -E "s/^[0-9]+ //" <<< "$path")"

       # Replaces impermissible characters in path basename
       # and subsitutes uppercase characters with lowercase.
       new_basename="$(sed "s/$IMPERMISSIBLE_CHARS/$REPLACEMENT_STRING/g" <<< \
           "$(basename "${path}")" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")"

       # Concatenate original dirname and new basename to form new path.
       new_path="$(dirname "${path}")"/"$new_basename"

       # Only rename the item when:
       # - New path does not already exist to prevent data loss.
       # - New basename length is less than or equal to 255 characters.
       if ! [ -e "$new_path" ] && [[ ${#new_basename} -le 255 ]]; then
         mv -n "$path" "$new_path"
       fi
     done
   }

   renameBaseName "${sorted_paths[@]}"
   ```
8. The completed canvas area of your Automator Service/Workflow should now appear something like this:

   [image]
9. Type <kbd>⌘S</kbd>, or choose `File` > `Save` from the Menu bar. Let's name the file `Replace Impermissible Chars`.

---

#### Running the Service:

1. In the *Finder*:

   - Select a *single* file or folder and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> to show the contextual menu
   - Select the `Replace Impermissible Chars` service in the contextual menu to run it.
2. Alternatively, in the *Finder*:

   - Select *multiple* files and/or folders and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> to show the contextual menu
   - Select the `Replace Impermissible Chars` service in the contextual menu to run it.

---

#### Notes:

1. The *Finder* will allow the Service to be run on up to 1000 files/folders selected at once.
2. If this is the first Automator Service you have created you **may** (if I've remembered correctly!) need to restart your computer for it to become available via the contextual pop-up menu.
3. The Bash Shell script will not replace impermissible characters in a file/folder name if either of the following two conditions are met:

   - If a file/folder name already exists which matches the name of a resultant new file/folder name. For example: Let's say we have a file named `hello-world.txt` and in the same folder a file named `hello?world.txt`. If we run the Service on `hello?world.txt`, it's name will not be corrected/changed as this would potentially overwrite the `hello-world.txt` file which already exists.
   - If the resultant file name is `>=` to 255 characters. This may of course only occur if you were to change the `REPLACEMENT_STRING` value (in the Bash/Shell script) to more than one character, instead of just a single hyphen `-`.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy with help of Regular Expression and the Foundation Framework bridged to AppleScriptObjC.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

use framework "Foundation"

set fileName to "New(Foo)*aBcd<B|r.ext"

set nsFileName to current application's NSString's stringWithString:fileName
set nsLowerCaseFileName to nsFileName's lowercaseString()
set trimmedFileName to (nsLowerCaseFileName's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"[()[\\/:\"*?<>|]+_]" withString:"-" options:(current application's NSRegularExpressionSearch) range:{location:0, |length|:nsLowerCaseFileName's |length|()}) as text
display dialog trimmedFileName
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your code to workflow and than run service through the context menu while select the name of flie. But after code completes I get notification: new-foo--abcd-b-r.ext

Comment: That's the `display dialog` line. Just remove it.

Comment: But the name of file does not change.

Comment: If you get `new-foo--abcd-b-r.ext` the name **has** changed. The result is in `trimmedFileName`. It just an example, the `fileName` is hard-coded. You have to embed the code in your environment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works great! Is there a way to simplify it and remove the "lower case" part of the code?

Comment: @JordanHe Delete the `lowercaseString()` line and in the next line replace `nsLowerCaseFileName's` with `nsFileName's`

Answer (score 1):

Two great solutions here.  But as every problem usually has many solutions, I offer another:

```
    property alphabet : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    rename from "HELLO World+Foo(\"Bar\")new.ext"
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ### HANDLERS
    #
    # rename from:
    #   Receives a text string and processes it for invalid characters, which
    #   get replaced with the specified replacement string (default: "-"),
    #   returning the result
    to rename from filename given disallowed:¬
        invalidCharSet as text : "[()[\\/:\"*?<>|]+_] ", replaceWith:¬
        replacementStr as text : "-"
        local filename
        local invalidCharSet, replacementStr

        set my text item delimiters to {replacementStr} & ¬
            the characters of the invalidCharSet

        text items of the filename as text

        makeLowercase(the result)
    end rename


    # makeLowercase():
    #   Receives a text string as input and returns the string formatted as
    #   lowercase text
    to makeLowercase(str as text)
        local str

        set my text item delimiters to ""

        if str = "" then return ""

        set [firstLetter, otherLetters] to [¬
            the first character, ¬
            the rest of the characters] of str


        tell the firstLetter to if ¬
            it is "-" or ¬
            it is not in the alphabet then ¬
            return it & my makeLowercase(the otherLetters)

        considering case
            set x to (offset of the firstLetter in the alphabet) mod 27
        end considering

        return character x of the alphabet & my makeLowercase(the otherLetters)
    end makeLowercase
```

This code can be used in a **Run AppleScript** *Automator* action, placing `rename from...` inside the `on run {input, parameters}` handler, and the rest of the code outside it.  It can follow an action that supplies it with a list of files in *Finder*, or it can receive its input directly from the workflow's input if it is run as a ***Service***.

```
    property alphabet : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    on run {input, parameters}
        tell application "Finder" to repeat with f in input
            set the name of f to (rename from f)
        end repeat
    end run

    to rename from ...
        .
        .
    end rename

    to makeLowercase(str as text)
        .
        .
    end makeLowercase
```