# macOS Finder service (via Automator) to replace "special chars" with dashes

Tags: macos, shell, automator, finder

I would like to create a Finder Services plugin with Automator that removes "special chars" [\W___]+ and replaces them with dashes. Could this eventually be achieved via a combination of sed and mv and then be added to the Automator workflow via "Run Shell Script"?

Background:
I composed an action like this in an app called ForkLift, see image [ForkLift RegEx Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK5Dg.png) but would love to have a similar function at hand in Finder as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing invalid characters in the filename with dashes using AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134550/replacing-invalid-characters-in-the-filename-with-dashes-using-applescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Replacing the selected text of a file name

Create a new *Automator* service.  Make sure it **`Receives input as text from Finder`**, and check the option to **`Replace selected text with output`** (or something of this ilk).

Add a **Run Shell Script** action that receives input from `stdin`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
input="$(</dev/stdin)"  # assign contents of stdin to variable
shopt -s extglob        # activate extended pattern matching
output="${input//+([![:alnum:]_])/-}" # replace runs of non-alphanumeric, non-underscore
                                      # characters with a single hyphen
printf '%s' "$output"   # print the result
```

#### Renaming a selected file

Create a new *Automator* service.  Make sure it **`Receives input as file/folder from Finder`**.

Add a **Run Shell Script** action that receives input **as arguments**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob        # activate extended pattern matching
for f in "$@"; do
    filename="$(basename "$f")"
    dirpath="$(dirname "$f")"

    filename="${filename//+([![:alnum:]_.])/-}"
    mv "$f" "$dirpath/$filename"
done
```

The slight difference in the renaming pattern is to prevent periods (`"."`) from being replaced, which would otherwise remove all file extensions.